# Issue with Cluster IP and its port once it goes down

Tags: rest, azure, spring-boot, kubernetes

Please consider below scenario:

1. I deploy a pod which is exposed as service and i am able to access it from browser as a Rest API. It also tries to connects to another api but it fails and proceeds with a dummy response from its client library which connects to this API 2.
2. Now I deploy the second API and configure it to run on ClusterIP config. Now i configure this CluserIP and port for API 1 which was created in step 1. I am able to get success response from API 1 by invoking it as REST API as in Step 1, the difference is I am getting additional response what API 2 sends.
3. Now I delete the service that was running API 2 and create it again. This creates a new Cluster IP it self there by leaving the APP 1 not able to contact on previous Cluster IP.
4. Now i am not even getting the old dummy response what API 2's client library was providing. what could be the cause?

So I have couple of questions based on above scenario:

1. Why is my API 1 not even getting dummy response from API 2 client lib atleast?
2. How do we deal with this scenario and make sure we have same ClusterIP for API 2 even when its service is deleted and created again.

Note: We are using AKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use service endpoint names, not IP addresses. they do not change (if the service is called the same).

if this is your service definition:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-front
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: azure-vote-front
```

you would be able to access it using its name: azure-vote-front. Your pods would also have environment variable with the service ip.